# Unable to run the Get-Service command in Powershell Ubuntu

Tags: powershell

I installed `Powershell` in Ubuntu and when I try the

```
Get-Service
```

command, it returns an error :

```
Get-Service: The term 'Get-Service' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is `Get-Service` a windows only command ?

Powershell version is `PowerShell 7.1.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in [the official MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service), this commandlet is only available on windows ... Meaning it's not available for macOS nor ubuntu at the moment.